# validate both models in a single form in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have two database, 1st one is for Group and the 2nd one is for Member. Now I want to validate the both models in a single form and the my group controller file is like this

```
public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Group;
    $member=new Member;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Group'],$_POST['Member']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Group'];
      //$member->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
      if($model->save())
      {
        $member->attributes=$_POST['Member'];
        $member->group_id = $model->id;
        if($member->save())
        {
          $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
      }
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'member'=>$member,
    ));
  }
```

So how to make validate both models here.

Comment: You mean that you want to validate both models before saving either of them?

Comment: Yes I want to validate both models before save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that extends `CFormModel`. This keeps your controller code simple and clean. Make sure it can be created with the default constructor. Then you pass in the data for the group and user, validate it, and then save it, like this:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $form = new CreateGroupForm();

    if (isset($_POST['Group'],$_POST['Member'])) {
        $form->setData($_POST['Group'], $_POST['Member']);
        if ($form->validate()) {
            $form->save();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The form class itself would create the group and member objects when you call `setData()`, and it simply validates both classes in `validate()`. Its `save()` method would look like you've done above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  $model->validate()
```

method to check if a model is valid or not

Comment: ya it is actually doing valid the first model but the second model is not doing any validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valid = $model1->validate();
$valid = $model2->validate() && $valid;

if($valid)
{
    //your code
}
```

It will validate both model.